# Connect domain with server

Tags: webserver, domain

I've got virtual server on Hetzner and I've purchased a domain from GoDaddy.
How do I point my domain to my server's ip and how should I setup my nameservers. I need detailed instruction as I'm kind of newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an "A" record to the DNS zone-data for your domain.

How you do this depends on your DNS service provider, In the case of GoDaddy [it should be something like](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238):

- Log on to GoDaddy
- Go to "Domains"
- Select the domain (e.g. baghdasaryan.com)
- Click "Manage DNS"
- Click "Add" to add a record
- Set the record type to "A"
- Put in in the hostname (e.g. "www")
- Put in the IP-address of the virtual server
- Click "Save"
- Wait (it may take 10 minutes or much more for the name to be usable worldwide)

This answer assumes IPV4. [The process for IPV6 may be similar](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/add-an-aaaa-record-19214).

Comment: Thank you very much! This was simple and accurate guide. Exactly what I needed.